# MySql Server 8 change table names to be case sensitive

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

I am trying to change the way table names are created in MySql Server 8 on Windows. I create a my.cnf file and placed it under bin folder with the following content

```
lower-case-table-names = 2
```

I restarted mysql service and still tables are created in lowercase.
I have renamed the file to my.ini but no luck.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you try to re-create the tables?

Comment: Yes I tried. I have even create a new database

Comment: Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix or Linux.

Comment: @RatishBansal what do you mean? I cannot have case sensitive table names in Windows?

Comment: @pantonis Windows file system is case insensitive; so basically OS itself does not allow case sensitive file names; hence you cant do case sensitive table names in Windows

Answer (score 0):

`Exception:` `InnoDB` Table names and View names are stored in lowercase, as for lower_case_table_names=1. Can you check if you are using `innoDB`

Refer the table in
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Yes I am using InnoDB

Comment: @pantonis Can you try to change it to any other engine, since the MySQL documentation mentioned that InnoDB only supports lower case names.